# 2 JOINS MYSQL and LIMIT 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables and want to make a sql query to proper view them.

1.) Zakaz

```
id | Comment
```

2.) Tovar

```
id  | id_clients | zakaz
```

3.) Users

```
id | name
```

They are connected as:

```
zakaz.id = tovar.zakaz
tovar.id_clients = users.id
```

I want to see

```
zakaz.id | users.name
```

BUT I want to limit only to 1 string per zakaz, so I did:

```
SELECT zakaz.id, zakaz.comment, tovar.id_clients
    FROM zakaz
    JOIN tovar ON zakaz.id = tovar.zakaz
GROUP BY zakaz.id
```

and then I want to JOIN users but it doesnt work

```
SELECT zakaz.id, zakaz.comment, tovar.id_clients, users.name
    FROM zakaz
    JOIN tovar ON zakaz.id = tovar.zakaz
    GROUP BY zakaz.id
JOIN users ON users.id = tovar.id_clients
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it will display the latest id on `Zakaz`

```
SELECT  a.name, c.id
FROM    Users a
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT id_clients, zakaz, MAX(id) maxID
                FROM Tovar
                GROUP BY id_clients, zakaz
            ) d 
                ON d.id_clients = a.id
            INNER JOIN Zakaz c
                ON d.zakaz = c.id
```